# Console application doesn't obey Thread.Join

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having trouble understanding why my console app doesn't wait until the thread it spawns **fully** terminates. I think this is related to the fact that the thread in question also spawns its own child threads and/or the inclusion of System.Timer

The basic program flow is as follows.  Main  creates a new thread against the Simulator.Start method, and then joins until that thread terminates.  Simulator.Start creates a new `Timer` (to constrain how long it should execute) and then creates/runs a bunch of child threads.  When the `Elapsed` event is raised by the `Timer`, this signals that the Simulator should terminate all of its child threads and generate a report.  The problem is that the console app exits as soon as all child threads terminate and the code to generate a report never gets executed (See Simulator.Stop method below).

Hopefully some pseudo code will help:

```
public class Program
{
    private static Simulator _simulator;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var options = new SimulationOptions();
        //check for valid options
        if (!Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, options)) return;

        _simulator = new Simulator(options);

        var thread = new Thread(_simulator.Start) {IsBackground = false};
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
    }
}

public class Simulator
{
    private readonly SimulationOptions _options;
    private readonly List<Thread> _threads = new List<Thread>();
    private readonly List<Worker> _workers = new List<Worker>();
    private static Timer _timer;

    public Simulator(SimulationOptions options)
    {
        _options = options;
        StartTimer(_options.LengthOfTest);
    }

    private void StartTimer(int lengthOfTest)
    {
        _timer = new Timer {Interval = lengthOfTest*1000};
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        Stop();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        // Request that the worker thread stop itself:
        foreach (Worker worker in _workers)
        {
            worker.RequestStop();
        }

        GenerateReport(); //<-- this code never gets executed
    }

    private XDocument GenerateReport()
    {
        //build an awesome report
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _threads.Clear();
        _workers.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < _options.NumberOfClients; i++)
        {
            _workers.Add(new Worker());
            _threads.Add(new Thread(_workers.Last().PumpMessages));
            _threads.Last().Start();
        }
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    private bool _shouldStop = false;

    public void PumpMessages()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            //does cool stuff until told to stop
        }
    }

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, it races through the Start() method, takes a few microseconds at most.  There just wasn't any point to call Start() on a worker thread in the first place.  You'll need to Join() all these threads you start.

Comment: The problem is not with the Start method.  The console application hangs around long enough for the Timer_Elapsed event, which triggers the Stop method.  However, execution ends midway through that method.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in your start method keeps the thread alive. When the following method finishes, so does the thread. You then call Thread.Join and that is the end of that.

```
public void Start()
{
    _threads.Clear();
    _workers.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < _options.NumberOfClients; i++)
    {
        _workers.Add(new Worker());
        _threads.Add(new Thread(_workers.Last().PumpMessages));
        _threads.Last().Start();
    }
}
```

If you intend on waiting for this work to complete, consider waiting on a ManualResetEvent for each worker thread that you are using.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitall.aspx

Your method should look something like the following.

```
public void Start()
{
    _threads.Clear();
    _workers.Clear();
    var evts = new List<ManualResetEvent>()
    for (int i = 0; i < _options.NumberOfClients; i++)
    {
        ManualResetEvent evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        evts.Add(evt);
        _workers.Add(new Worker(evt));
        _threads.Add(new Thread(_workers.Last().PumpMessages));
        _threads.Last().Start();
    }
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(evts.ToArray());
}

public class Worker
{
    private bool _shouldStop = false;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent @event;

    public Worker(ManualResetEvent @event)
    {
        this.@event = @event;
    }
    public void PumpMessages()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            //does cool stuff until told to stop
        }
        @event.Set();
    }
    public void RequestStop()
    {
        _shouldStop = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, use tasks.

Comment: Yes, or better yet, use the Task Parallel Library with async/await. But if you are just learning about threads, this is a good exercise to go through.

Comment: Oh, definitely. It always helps to learn some of the pitfalls of the underlying technology before jumping to the shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

Join method waits only for thread instance you joined, so `Simulator.Start` just creates some threads and it terminates, as the result `Join` returns and your main thread terminates. But still your App is alive(reason some other Foreground threads are still running).

```
generate a report never gets executed? Why?
```

Process will terminate when all `Foreground Threads` terminates. so as soon as your child threads return from `PumpMessages` method when you call `RequestStop` in a loop, all of your foreground threads terminates

```
public void Stop()
{
    // Request that the worker thread stop itself:
    foreach (Worker worker in _workers)
    {
        worker.RequestStop();
    }
    <--here all foreground threads are ready to terminate
    GenerateReport(); //<-- this code never gets executed
}
```

It was little misleading that I stated that `all foreground threads die after the loop`. To make it clear let's say that we have given instruction for the worker threads to stop working, so all threads may or may not die before executing `GenerateReport` method. yes there is a [Race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) If worker threads wins the race then we lose it, and viceversa. sometimes your `GenerateReport` may execute without any problem.

How to fix it? We just wait for all our worker threads to terminate. that's it.

```
public void Start()
{
    _threads.Clear();
    _workers.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < _options.NumberOfClients; i++)
    {
        _workers.Add(new Worker());
        _threads.Add(new Thread(_workers.Last().PumpMessages));
        _threads.Last().Start();
    }
    foreach (var t in _threads)
       t.Join();
}
```

Comment: I like your answer better than mine, but I think your explanation of Stop is not thorough. It is not exactly that "all foreground threads die". It is that there is a race condition because Stop is called from a timer thread and there is nothing here to coordinate the Stop method with the main execution. None the less, your solution of t.Join is the way to go.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens I was about to leave, just answered in a hurry, let me revise it

Comment: I added the join statements to the Start method, but that made no difference.  Just wanted to make sure you knew that the Console thread hangs around until the Stop method executes...but it bails before GenerateReports.

Comment: Can you call `GenerateReport` before stopping childs? if that helps